# Queue for an api call using react with redux?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, axios

I am handling the scenario that whenever i make more than one api call, it should not call all the api's simultaneously rather it should push to the queue whenever api call in progress and once i get the response i have to make a api call from queue if the queue length is greater than 0.

```
let queueToBeExecuted = [];
let apiInProgressCheck = false;
const apiInProgressCheckFn = (data,url) => {
  apiInProgressCheck = data;
  if (apiInProgressCheck === true ){
    queueToBeExecuted.push(url);
    console.log('queue', queueToBeExecuted)
  }
  else {
    const itemToAdd = queueToBeExecuted.shift();
    console.log('shift', queueToBeExecuted) 
    // i have to make a api call again
  }
  return apiInProgressCheck;
}



const makingAnApiCall = async (url) => {
   response = await axios({ url, method: get });
    if (response.status) {
      apiInProgressCheckFn(false, url);
      if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
        dispatch(success(response));
      } else {
        dispatch(failed(response));
      }
    }



};

export default makingAnApiCall;
```

I have created the javascript function named 'makingAnApiCall', whenever i called this function api call will get triggered and dispatching the respective actions based on the response and also the values of local variables has been resetted. So i could not able to stop the api's getting  called. Can any one help in achieving this queue for api calls and suggest me the best approach in order to achieve the same using either javascript or react with redux?

Comment: That would make your application much slower, do you want to do this because of making api calls based on user input and you only want to resolve the last?

Comment: yea based on the user input..

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question, you would like to find a way to perform these API calls once the previous API call has been executed ?

Comment: You could only resolve if it's the last user input. Maybe [this](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js#L346-L392) can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to use [onlyLastRequestedPromise](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js#L346-L392):

```
const makingAnApiCall = async (url, last = x => x) => {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await last(axios({ url, method: get }));
  } catch (e) {
    if (e === 'A newer request was made.') {
      //ignore this error, current request replaced
      //  with newer one
      return;
    }
    //something else went wrong, rethrow the error
    throw e;
  }
  if (response.status) {
    apiInProgressCheckFn(false, url);
    if (
      response.status === 200 ||
      response.status === 201
    ) {
      dispatch(success(response));
    } else {
      dispatch(failed(response));
    }
  }
};
//IIFE to initialize last only once
const lastSearchApiResult = (() => {
  const last = onlyLastRequestedPromise('search');
  return url => makingAnApiCall(url, last);
})();
```